# Path Twig Strange conversion of the string Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony, twig, sugar.js

I have this variable

```
   {% set slug_profilo_segnalato = '{slug_profilo_segnalato}' %}
```

(i assign {slug_profilo_segnalato} via sugar.js with assign. (http://sugarjs.com/api/String/assign)
if i do {{slug_profilo_segnalato}}, i see correct (p.e william)

```
<a href='{{ path('profilo', {'slug': slug_profilo_segnalato }) }}'
```

when I look at the link I generated this result

```
.../profilo/%7Bslug_profilo_segnalato%7D
```

To solve this problem I did the following:

```
 <a href='{{ path('profilo', {'slug': slug_profilo_segnalato })|replace({'%7B':'{', '%7D':'}'}) }}'>PROFILO</a>
```

The results on Twig:

```
../profilo/william
```

I do not think that is the best solution. 
i try also |raw, spaceless..
Why is encoded in this way?

Answer (score 1):

%7B and %7D means you have the value with braces like this one "{something_here}"
that means sugarjs don't remove braces or twig method path runs before sugarjs

Comment: the strange thing is that if I do {{slug_profilo_segnalato}} I see my variable correctly (eg William) ... without Extra characters

Comment: I had this and apparently a bracket had slipped in somewhere haha

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried combining `autoescape` block and `raw` filter?

```
{% autoescape false %}
    <a href='{{ path('profilo', {'slug': slug_profilo_segnalato|raw }) }}'
{% endautoescape %}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i try this but i have the same path (/%7Bslug_profilo_segnalato%7D)